# how to use StatsModel ARMA model to make a better prediction

Tags: python

In this website about a ARMA model
      http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/examples/notebooks/generated/tsa_arma.html#Exercise:-How-good-of-in-sample-prediction-can-you-do-for-another-series,-say,-CPI

I cant not understand this sentences,how to use select_order to make a better prediction?

"Can you obtain a better fit for the Sunspots model? (Hint: sm.tsa.AR has a method select_order)"

Answer (score 1):

The hint appears to be broken.  See:  https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/2118   .  So you cannot use select_order on AR, I think.

For a work-around, they recommend using arma_order_select_ic.  If you follow along the example in the page you reference, you have a data object called dta.  Then you can do that following:

```
res = sm.tsa.arma_order_select_ic(dta, max_ar=10, max_ma=0, ic='bic')
print(res)

{'bic_min_order': (9, 0), 'bic':               0
0   3174.049905
1   2830.369176
2   2637.569703
3   2638.070335
4   2642.878700
5   2648.610908
6   2645.594430
7   2635.308015
8   2625.737548
9   2611.689366
10  2617.421383}
```

I *think* this means that the MLE is decreasing as the order increases for the first several, but then levels off, so using a lag of 7 or 8 is the highest you should go.  However, I'm not sure.